# Is there a way to put two pspicture's side by side?

Tags: beamer, pstricks

I am making slides using Beamer, and I am trying to have to `\pspicture`s side by side.  However, no matter what I do they end up one under the other, even if I use `minipage`.  What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I forgot one crucial detail: the paragraph break between the minipages.

Comment: That's strange: you don't need `\hspace` between minipages, however you have to make sure there is no paragraph break (empty line) between them.

Comment: You are right, that was it!

Comment: @ Dima Would you put the code which you used to put these two pspicture beside each other? because I do it through their coordinate and want to know how you do it ? tnx

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that they are small enough to fit next to each other? If not, you might need to resize them.

Answer (score 2):

Make two columns using `\begin{columns}` and `\begin{column}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{\textbackslash pspicture side by side}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering%
\pspicture[showgrid](4,4)
\endpspicture
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering%
\pspicture[showgrid](4,4)
\endpspicture
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried it with book document class , but I encountered the error that the column environment is unknown , should I add any further package ?

Comment: @Negin: `column` is defined in `beamer` class (not in a package).